# Find a number in a html tag with Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am creating a web scraping of a certain page. The problem I have is that you have to click on a specific element, which has `onclick = "phoneContactFromAdList (353966494, 0);"`. Along this same line, there is a class called ***def-button***.

The problem is that since there are several product buttons, the number '353966494' is constantly changing. What options do I have to be able to obtain a list containing these numbers, to replace them every time I have to click the button? It is Selenium with Python.

**************Edited**************
The problem I am realizing I have is this. (It does not let me delete the post, so I will add it here).

My code is this.

```
import random
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')


lenPaginas = driver.find_element_by_class_name("adlist-paginator-summary")

codigo_de_elementos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name = ('X5')
print(codigo_de_elementos)
print("%s max paginas = %s" % (lenPaginas.text, lenPaginas.text.split(" ")[3]))

for i in range(int(lenPaginas.text.split(" ")[3]) + 1): # Voy a darle click en cargar mas 3 veces
#Para conseguir los identificadores de los botones de contacto javascripts
    print(i)
    for codigosAutos in codigo_de_elementos:
        sleep(5)
        primeraParteDatos = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='phoneContactFromAdList(%s, 0);']" % codigosAutos)
        sleep(random.uniform(4.0,8.0))
        print(primeraParteDatos)
```

What I want to do is access the elements of the page https://www.milanuncios.com/coches-de-segunda-mano-en-cadiz/ with selenium Python. But for some reason it won't allow me. My intention is to click the 'Call' element and then, if the page asks for it, click where it asks me if I really want to see the data, and store that data in a variable. This with all the elements of the page, but for some reason it does not allow me to access the data. I already tried many ways. The most frequent error it shows me is selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "xpath", "selector": "// a [@ onclick = 'phoneContactFromAdList (X, 0); '] "}
(Session info: chrome = 83.0.4103.116).
If anyone can help me with that, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Provide me more context about your code So that Anyone can help you out easily :)

Comment: You've got a semi colon in your xpath. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add more information about element and where it locates but I think copying the class or using XPath method could be useful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.YourDriverOfChoice(executable_path="Full path to the browser drivers located")
driver.get("site you're looking for")
elem_you_looking = driver.find_element_by_id("elements id")
```

or you can use different methods for finding elements like

### XPath, class name, CSS_selector, link text, partial link text

Welcome Stack, by the way; I also used Selenium for scraping but I didn't find it very strong there is better modules for scraping like b4s (Beautiful Soup) you should give it a shot.

Comment: Hi! In summary, what I need is to be able to find the number that comes within the label that I left above, knowing only that it is accompanied. For example, being able to know the rest of the label knowing only that it is made up of phoneContactFromAdList plus a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath contains method on an attribute to find your static part of your identifier, then will get the object

Try:

```
.find_elements_with_xpath ("//*[contains(@onclick,'phoneContactFromA')]")
```

Find element will work if there is one object that matches (but fail if there are many) Find elements will find all that match and you can integrate through them.

*[edit - now i have the link i can be more accurate!]*

The first part of your code successfully gets the dynamic data (the number).

Feed that into this xpath:

```
//div[contains(@id,'350094913')]//a[contains(@onclick,'phoneContactFromAdList')]
```

Note that with the `X5` class you retrieve **r**XXXX - this object needs just the number so you'll need to do some string manipulation to keep just the numerical characters.

That XPath will find the parent container select the relevant object for the click.

When i look at the link this generates unique objects:

[image]

Comment: updated based on the extra info provided - thanks for that @juan